# Compare two lists and modify element if different

Tags: python, list

I want to create a new list by comparing two equal sized lists and keeping the value if they match, and setting it to a fixed value if they don't. For example, if I compared the following two lists with a fixed value of `-1`:

```py
fixed_value = -1
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,3,2,5]
```

The output here should be `[1, -1, 3, -1, 5]`.

Is there any neat way to do so, perhaps using a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension and include an if statement to check your condition. This solution uses [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both lists at the same time. `zip()` is a Python built-in is able to "(i)terate over several iterables in parallel, producing tuples with an item from each one.":

```py
result = [
    a_element if a_element == b_element else fixed_value
    for a_element, b_element in zip(a, b)
]
```

Iterating both `a` and `b` at the same time, you compare the elements. If they're the same, just use one of them (they're equal), but in other case use your `fixed_value`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` and a list comprehension.

```py
fixed_value = -1
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,3,2,5]

result = [item1 if item1 == item2 else fixed_value for item1, item2 in zip(a, b)]
print(result) # Prints [1, -1, 3, -1, 5]
```

`zip()` produces an iterable of tuples, where the first element is `(a[0], b[0])`, the second is `(a[1], b[1])`, etc. Then, we can check the elements in these tuples for equality; if they're equal, we add the first element in our tuple to the list, else we output `-1`.